# Data Studio : calculated fields show current value

Tags: database, case, looker-studio

I'm using Google data studio and I need to group some data.

I have a column with some codes (3 Letters words) and I want to group all codes beginning with  `A` and for the others I want to keep the value. 
I did something like this but the `Else` clause doesn't work.

```
CASE
   WHEN NOT REGEXP_MATCH(Codes, '[A]*') THEN "Others"
   ELSE Codes
END
```

How can I keep the value of the field in a certain case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of the following [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058) [Calculated Fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685) will do the trick where `^` indicates the beginning of the value:

### 1) **Others = Begins with B to Z:**

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Codes, "^([B-Z].*)", "Others")
```

### 2) **Others = Begins with A:**

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Codes, "^(A.*)", "Others")
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/514f5f59-65cd-42f6-877b-df05e4f3de9a) and a GIF to demonstrate:

[image]